# Reindex DataFrame Columns by Label Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, reindex

I have a Series of Labels

```
pd.Series(['L1', 'L2', 'L3'], ['A', 'B', 'A'])
```

and a dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], ['I1', 'I2'], ['A', 'B'])
```

I'd like to have a dataframe with columns `['L1', 'L2', 'L3']` with the column data from 'A', 'B', 'A' respectively. Like so...

```
pd.DataFrame([[1,2,1], [3,4,3]], ['I1', 'I2'], ['L1', 'L2', 'L3'])
```

in a nice pandas way.

Comment: Would you like create the sample data and show your expected result ?

Comment: Hopefully, that is helpful in clarifying.  The real problem has many labels and is a largish dataframe.

Comment: I think reindex is the right solution, but I can't seem to write it the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention `reindex`

```
#s=pd.Series(['L1', 'L2', 'L3'], ['A', 'B', 'A'])
#df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], ['I1', 'I2'], ['A', 'B'])
df.reindex(s.index,axis=1).rename(columns=s.to_dict())
Out[598]: 
    L3  L2  L3
I1   1   2   1
I2   3   4   3
```

Comment: If there is a cleaner way without `reindex` I'm happy to use that, but this looks great.

Comment: @rhaskett `df.loc[:,s.index].rename(columns=s.to_dict())
`

Answer (score 1):

This will produce the dataframe you described:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['A','B','A','A','B','B'],
        ['B','B','B','A','B','B'],
        ['A','B','A','B','B','B']]

columns = ['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'L5', 'L6']

pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loc` accessor:

```
s = pd.Series(['L1', 'L2', 'L3'], ['A', 'B', 'A'])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], ['I1', 'I2'], ['A', 'B'])

res = df.loc[:, s.index]

print(res)

    A  B  A
I1  1  2  1
I2  3  4  3
```

Or `iloc` accesor with `columns.get_loc`:

```
res = df.iloc[:, s.index.map(df.columns.get_loc)]
```

Both methods allows accessing duplicate labels / locations, in the same vein as NumPy arrays.